# Writer abstract class: why write(int c) writes a single character but locates 1024 locations?

Tags: java, writer

Abstract class `Writer` we have this abstract method that writes a portion of an array of characters.

```
abstract public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

Also look at this method inside `Writer` class that writes a single character:

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (writeBuffer == null){
                writeBuffer = new char[writeBufferSize];
            }
            writeBuffer[0] = (char) c;
            write(writeBuffer, 0, 1);
        }
    }
```

The size **writeBufferSize**= 1024.
I am sure there is a good reason for using an array of 1024 locations for wring one character, can anyone explain to me what's the reason?
Thanks

Comment: It's a nice, round number.

Comment: Is `writeBuffer` used anywhere else? It looks like yes because of the synchronized section. It might just be used in different locations with different size requirements and using one buffer might save memory.

Comment: The `writeBuffer` gets reused -- it's not allocating a new 1024-char array for each character.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments, I wish you could give the answer with more details.